# My Apricots have raised brown bumps on them, any idea what they are?

Tags: diagnosis, fruits, apricots

This Apricot tree is producing fruit which has raised brown bumps on the flesh.
Does anyone recognise what these are?
The tree is located in the North Eastern suburbs of Melbourne, Australia.

Thank you in advance

[image: Brown bumps on apricots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely one of the Freckle diseases, which are primarily fungal in origin. You need to check the twigs and branches for signs of problems on those to confirm what the actual problem is, but from the images, it does look likely it's a form of scab, see here: [Stone fruit scab (or freckle)](https://agriculture.vic.gov.au/biosecurity/plant-diseases/fruit-and-nut-diseases/stone-fruits/stone-fruit-scab-or-freckle).

Comment: Is it mostly on the upper surface? just curious.